# How to change a value of the element without reloading after a button element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, button

I am trying to implement a “Like” button for each post. I want to change the class of the button element based on whether the user has liked the post or not, and I want the change to be reflected in real-time without a full page reload. So far, the button can send data that is like or not to a function of Django using fetch however the change of the data isn’t reflected without reloading. To achieve this, what does it need to modify?

**Button element in html file**

```
<div id="{{ post.id }}">
    {% if post.id in whoyouliked %}
    <button class="btn btn-secondary fa fa-thumbs-down" onclick="likeHandler(`{{ post.id }}`, `{{ whoyouliked }}`)"></button>
    {% else %}
    <button class="btn btn-info fa fa-thumbs-up" onclick="likeHandler(`{{ post.id }}`, `{{ whoyouliked }}`)"></button>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**likeHandler function in script tag in the same html file**

```
function likeHandler(id, whoyouliked){
    let btn = document.getElementById(`${id}`);

    btn.classList.remove('fa-thumbs-up')
    btn.classList.remove('fa-thumbs-down')
    if(whoyouliked.indexOf(id) >= 0){
        var liked = true;
    } else{
        var liked = false;
    }

    if(liked === true){
        fetch(`remove_like/${id}`)
        .then(response => response.json)
        .then(result => {
            btn.classList.add('fa-thumbs-up')
        })
    } else{
        fetch(`add_like/${id}`)
        .then(response => response.json)
        .then(result => {
            btn.classList.add('fa-thumbs-down')
        })
    }
}
```

I'm new to javascript, so I'd appreciate any comment.

#### 31/08/2023 edit by Kosuke

I revised above code like this. After I revised, “Like” button can change without loading though it can be only the first click. Without loading later than a second click, it can’t be changed.

**Button element in html file**

```
<div id="div{{ post.id }}"> <!--Added "div"-->
    {% if post.id in whoyouliked %}
    <button id="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-secondary fa fa-thumbs-down" onclick="likeHandler(`{{ post.id }}`, `{{ whoyouliked }}`)"></button> <!--Added id parameter-->
    {% else %}
    <button id="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-info fa fa-thumbs-up" onclick="likeHandler(`{{ post.id }}`, `{{ whoyouliked }}`)"></button> <!--Added id parameter--> 
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**likeHandler function in script tag in the same html file**

```
        function likeHandler(id, whoyouliked){
            let btn = document.getElementById(`${id}`);

            // Commented out below two lines.
            // btn.classList.remove('fa-thumbs-up')
            // btn.classList.remove('fa-thumbs-down')
            btn.setAttribute("class", "")  // Added this line.
            if(whoyouliked.indexOf(id) >= 0){
                var liked = true;
            } else{
                var liked = false;
            }

            if(liked === true){
                fetch(`remove_like/${id}`)
                .then(response => response.json)
                .then(result => {
                    // Commented out 
                    // btn.classList.add('btn btn-info fa fa-thumbs-up')
                    // Added below four lines
                    btn.classList.add('btn')
                    btn.classList.add('btn-info')
                    btn.classList.add('fa')
                    btn.classList.add('fa-thumbs-up')
                })
            } else{
                fetch(`add_like/${id}`)
                .then(response => response.json)
                .then(result => {
                    // Commented out 
                    // btn.classList.add('btn btn-secondary fa fa-thumbs-down')
                    // Added below four lines
                    btn.classList.add('btn')
                    btn.classList.add('btn-info')
                    btn.classList.add('fa')
                    btn.classList.add('fa-thumbs-down')
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are getting wrong DOM element at the first line of your 'likeHandler' function.
You should give some unique ID into like/dislike button element. and get button element with that ID. It will work.

Comment: You need an AJAX call to get the like without a reload.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Fixed the code. Much improved. However, clicking the "Like" button after the second time does not reflect the button change.